# The UFD field lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

[This](http://www.mathreference.com/ag,fgaf.html) page contains a result which it refers to as the UFD field lemma. I was wondering if anybody knew of any other references which discuss this result--this page is the only place I've seen it.

The UFD field lemma appears to assert that if $R$ is a unique factorization domain containing infinitely many prime elements, if $F$ is the field of fractions of $R$, and if $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra which is a field and is algebraic over $F$, then $A$ does not contain $F$.

I'm looking for other sources because I find the exposition on that page a little hard to follow.

Comment: See Proposition 7.8 in Atiyah-Macdonald, where in their notation, A=R, B=F, and C=A (your A).

Comment: If you are interested in the Nullstellensatz you might
like to see Dan Bernstein's take on it at
http://cr.yp.to/zgk.html .

Comment: Thanks very much for the references!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might find it helpful to first comprehend the essence of the matter in a slightly simpler context, e.g. see the [proof I gave on sci.math on 22 Apr 2009](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/sci.math/_-sKN_SajfI/L4SXcx9eD7AJ). The key ideas are already there. Generally, I recommend Kaplansky, Commutative Rings, for the circle of ideas  around the generalized Nullstellensatz (Goldman, Krull, Zariski).